# Failed to stop testeci.service: Interactive authentication required

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins, integração-contínua

Estou tentando reiniciar um serviço no sucesso da execução de um JOB no jenkins. Tudo funciona, exceto o fato do jenkins não conseguir executar o comando `systemctl restart testeci.service`. Ele me retorna o erro abaixo:

```
Failed to stop logicaldelivery.service: Interactive authentication required.
See system logs and 'systemctl status testeci.service' for details.
Failed to start testeci.service: Interactive authentication required.
See system logs and 'systemctl status testeci.service' for details.
Failed to restart testeci.service: Interactive authentication required.
See system logs and 'systemctl status testeci.service' for details.
```

Ao executar o comando pelo usuário no terminal, ele funciona. O problema é apenas quando executo ele via Jenkins.

Alguém consegue me auxiliar?

Comment: Não entendi o motivo da negativação.. Se puderem informar o motivo, agradeço.

Comment: O downvote **não é meu**, mas realmente sua pergunta esta difícil de ajudar, até aonde me parece você não configurou o seu repositório ou tem algo ambíguo, acho que para a pergunta ser respondível é sempre necessário informar detalhes mínimos necessários para reproduzir o problema. Para resumir, a mensagem parece apenas afirmar que não configurou o seu testecil.service para autenticar, ou os dados estão incorretos. Tente fazer o que o programa pede, execute o comando `systemctl status testeci.service` e diga o que retorna.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento entendo, mas meu problema é exatamente esse, ao executar o comando pelo próprio terminal tudo funciona... Mas quando parte de um job no jenkins ele apresenta esse erro. Se eu digitar esse comando, tudo vai ocorrer como deve, mas gostaria que o Jenkins fizesse isso.

Comment: E o testeci.service é encontrado "globalmente" em qualquer pasta que digitar o comando? Ou você tem que digitar na pasta aonde ele é localizado?

Comment: Quando você executa manualmente você executa no teu usuário ou no SUDO? [

Comment: Não, sem SUDO, eu criei ele no /etc/systemd/system/testeci.service. Após isso executei o reload do daemon.

Comment: Ok, e tentou tudo o que eu disse antes?

Comment: Sim @GuilhermeNascimento, ele mostra que o serviço tá rodando normalmente (isso porque eu executei na mão antes o systemctl start testeci).

Comment: ok, vou perguntar de novo, tentou colocar o comando `systemctl status testeci.service` no Jenkins para ver o que ele retorna?

Comment: Perdão @GuilhermeNascimento agora entendi o que quis dizer. Não eu não coloquei. Executei pelo meu usuário. Vou fazer, obrigado